# pulling javascript code from database, inserting it via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have a mysql database some of whose fields hold javascript widgets:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.my-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506180.shtml&div=div_teambatting"></script>
```

I'm reading out the database fields via jquery. How do I insert and execute that widget code onto my web page? So far, I get the error, "VM60117:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

```
$.post('php/getGame.php', {thisDate: dateString, thisTeam: thisTeam}, function(returnedData) {
                
                if (returnedData.length) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( returnedData );
                    
                    var str = obj["opposing_team_box_score"];
                    $('#opposing_boxscore').preprend( eval(str) );
                    
                }
                
            });
```

Edit:

Here is my parsedJSON object:

```
Object {gameID: "2", game_date: "2015-06-17", score: "Pirates 3, White Sox 2   ", headline: "Seven in a row: Pirates defeat White Sox, 3-2   ", headline_url: "http://www.post-gazette.com/sports/pirates/2015/06…ates-defeat-White-Sox-3-2/stories/201506170231   "…}gameID: "2"game_code: "1498675"game_date: "2015-06-17"headline: "Seven in a row: Pirates defeat White Sox, 3-2   "headline_url: "http://www.post-gazette.com/sports/pirates/2015/06/17/Streaking-Pirates-defeat-White-Sox-3-2/stories/201506170231   "image_caption: "Pirates catcher Francisco Cervelli, left, and third baseman Jung Ho Kang smile after colliding after Cervelli caught a popup by Chicago during the seventh inning in Chicago.   "image_cutline: "David Banks/Associated Press   "image_url: "http://www.post-gazette.com/image/2015/06/17/ca0,0,3454,2469/Pirates-White-Sox-Baseball-1.jpg   "opposing_team: "White Sox, whitesox"opposing_team_box_score: "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting"></script>"opposing_team_pitching_box: "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxpitching"></script>"other_info_text: "Umpires: HP - Alfonso Marquez, 1B - Dan Bellino, 2B - Tom Hallion, 3B - Bruce Dreckman.
↵Time of Game: 2:27.
↵Attendance: 19,194.
↵Start Time Weather: 69° F, Wind 5mph from Left to Right, Overcast, No Precipitation."pirates_box_score: "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_PittsburghPiratesbatting"></script>"pirates_pitching_box: "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_PittsburghPiratespitching"></script>"score: "Pirates 3, White Sox 2   "star1_explainer: "Jung Ho Kang was the star of the game.  "star1_name: "jung_ho_kang"star1_stat: "1"stat1: "35"stat1_explainer: "Number of scoreless innings that Pirates pitchers had held opponents to before this game."story1_bold: "Pirates Notebook:"story1_head: "Hurdle follows Banister and Rangers from afar"story1_url: "http://www.post-gazette.com/sports/pirates/2015/06/18/Pirates-notebook-Hurdle-follows-Banister-and-Rangers-from-afar/stories/201506180115"story2_bold: "Pirates Blog: "story2_head: "Jeff Lockes' best stuff and the end of the streaks"story2_url: "http://sportsblogs.post-gazette.com/sports/pirates-pirates-blog"story3_bold: ""story3_head: ""story3_url: ""text_under_opposing_team_box_score: "2B: M Cabrera (7, off J Locke).
↵HBP: A Eaton (3, by J Locke).
↵TB: M Cabrera 3; A Garcia; J Abreu.
↵RBI: M Cabrera (22); A Garcia (26).
↵2-out RBI: A Garcia; M Cabrera.
↵Team LOB: 4.
↵With RISP: 1 for 2."text_under_pirates_box_score: "2B: J Harrison (16, off J Danks).
↵HR: J Kang (4, off J Danks, 1st inn, 1 on, 1 out to Deep RF Line).
↵SH: S Marte (2, off J Danks).
↵TB: J Kang 4; A McCutchen 2; J Harrison 2; S Rodriguez.
↵RBI: J Kang 2 (24); A McCutchen (42).
↵Team LOB: 2.
↵With RISP: 1 for 1.
↵Fielding
↵DP: 1. F Cervelli."text_under_pitching_boxes: "Balks: None.
↵WP: None.
↵HBP: J Locke (3; A Eaton).
↵IBB: None.
↵Pickoffs: None."__proto__: Object
```

Further edit:
Here is the returnedData:

```
{"gameID":"2","game_date":"2015-06-17","score":"Pirates 3, White Sox 2   ","headline":"Seven in a row: Pirates defeat White Sox, 3-2   ","headline_url":"http:\/\/www.post-gazette.com\/sports\/pirates\/2015\/06\/17\/Streaking-Pirates-defeat-White-Sox-3-2\/stories\/201506170231   ","image_url":"http:\/\/www.post-gazette.com\/image\/2015\/06\/17\/ca0,0,3454,2469\/Pirates-White-Sox-Baseball-1.jpg   ","image_cutline":"David Banks\/Associated Press   ","image_caption":"Pirates catcher Francisco Cervelli, left, and third baseman Jung Ho Kang smile after colliding after Cervelli caught a popup by Chicago during the seventh inning in Chicago.   ","opposing_team":"White Sox, whitesox","story1_url":"http:\/\/www.post-gazette.com\/sports\/pirates\/2015\/06\/18\/Pirates-notebook-Hurdle-follows-Banister-and-Rangers-from-afar\/stories\/201506180115","story1_bold":"Pirates Notebook:","story1_head":"Hurdle follows Banister and Rangers from afar","story2_url":"http:\/\/sportsblogs.post-gazette.com\/sports\/pirates-pirates-blog","story2_bold":"Pirates Blog: ","story2_head":"Jeff Lockes' best stuff and the end of the streaks","story3_url":"","story3_bold":"","story3_head":"","star1_name":"jung_ho_kang","star1_stat":"1","star1_explainer":"Jung Ho Kang was the star of the game.  ","stat1":"35","stat1_explainer":"Number of scoreless innings that Pirates pitchers had held opponents to before this game.","game_code":"1498675","opposing_team_box_score":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/widgets.sports-reference.com\/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting\"><\/script>","text_under_opposing_team_box_score":"2B: M Cabrera (7, off J Locke).\r\nHBP: A Eaton (3, by J Locke).\r\nTB: M Cabrera 3; A Garcia; J Abreu.\r\nRBI: M Cabrera (22); A Garcia (26).\r\n2-out RBI: A Garcia; M Cabrera.\r\nTeam LOB: 4.\r\nWith RISP: 1 for 2.","pirates_box_score":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/widgets.sports-reference.com\/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_PittsburghPiratesbatting\"><\/script>","text_under_pirates_box_score":"2B: J Harrison (16, off J Danks).\r\nHR: J Kang (4, off J Danks, 1st inn, 1 on, 1 out to Deep RF Line).\r\nSH: S Marte (2, off J Danks).\r\nTB: J Kang 4; A McCutchen 2; J Harrison 2; S Rodriguez.\r\nRBI: J Kang 2 (24); A McCutchen (42).\r\nTeam LOB: 2.\r\nWith RISP: 1 for 1.\r\nFielding\r\nDP: 1. F Cervelli.","opposing_team_pitching_box":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/widgets.sports-reference.com\/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxpitching\"><\/script>","pirates_pitching_box":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/widgets.sports-reference.com\/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506170.shtml&div=div_PittsburghPiratespitching\"><\/script>","text_under_pitching_boxes":"Balks: None.\r\nWP: None.\r\nHBP: J Locke (3; A Eaton).\r\nIBB: None.\r\nPickoffs: None.","other_info_text":"Umpires: HP - Alfonso Marquez, 1B - Dan Bellino, 2B - Tom Hallion, 3B - Bruce Dreckman.\r\nTime of Game: 2:27.\r\nAttendance: 19,194.\r\nStart Time Weather: 69\u00b0 F, Wind 5mph from Left to Right, Overcast, No Precipitation."}         string
```

Comment: The first script tag is doing what exactly ?

Comment: If you paste it on a web page, it shows a baseball game box score.

Comment: That may be your error - the url in that script tag goes to a parked domain at http://www.buydomains.com/ for me

Comment: Here's the actual widget: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=br&url=%2Fboxes%2FCHA%2FCHA201506180.shtml&div=div_ChicagoWhiteSoxbatting"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `jQuery.getScript()` to load your script.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: How would I get the widget on my page in a particular spot, then? var url = "mywidget.js";
$.getScript( url, function() {
     $('#opposing_boxscore').preprend( url );
}); ??? doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the `jQuery.parseJSON` function:

[image: jQuery.parseJSON("<script></script>") throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <]

From your question, it seems unlikely that you've used [JSON](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=json) before, or understand what it is; at least, not well enough to know that it has nothing to do with your question. Check out [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/json/), it may help you better understand JSON.

But anyway, in JSON, the left angle-bracket (`<`), and in fact most characters other than `{}"",:[]`, are invalid outside of string literals and object keys.

To fix this, avoid using the `parseJSON` function on the `returnedData` string.

Instead, could try something like:

```
if (returnedData.length) $('#opposing_boxscore').prepend(returnedData);
```

That should insert the script tag into your page.

---

Apparently, `returnedData` is a string consisting of more than just one script tag.

To access individual elements within `returnedData`, you can use jQuery's [`.find` API](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
if (returnedData.length) {
    var asjQuery = $("<div/>").html(returnedData).contents();
    $('#opposing_boxscore').prepend(
        asjQuery.find("script[src=http://widgets.my-reference.com/wg...]")
    );
}
```

Of course, if `returnedData` is also not a DOM string, then I need more info to fix the problem.

Comment: the problem is, returnedData is all fields from my database. I have to parseJSON in order to be able to separate the fields and call them where I need them. I just need to put the fields that hold the javascript code where I need them.

Comment: @LauraNMS to check what is going wrong, try replacing your current success callback code stuff  with:`if (returnedData.length) console.log(returnedData, typeof returnedData);`using that you should be able to see what is actually being returned, an object or something else.

Comment: It says "string". But again, I'm trying to deal with part of returnedData, not the whole thing.

Comment: @LauraNMS can you put the result of `console.log(returnedData)` into your answer? It will help solve the problem.

Comment: please see my edited answer above, where I show the parsedJSON, which shows all parts of what's coming out of the database.

Comment: @LauraNMS Is that the value of `returnedData`? I hope you haven't called `parseJSON` on it...

Comment: I've added the returnedData above with the parseJSON.